# regex to removes single and double quotes

Tags: php, regex

Here's the regex where replaces all spaces and dot with - but without single and double quotes.

```
$name = htmlspecialchars(trim(@$_POST["name"],' '),ENT_QUOTES); 
$url = preg_replace("![^a-zA-Z0-9]+!i", "-", strtolower(htmlspecialchars(@$_POST["name"],ENT_QUOTES)));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have converted all single and double quotes into html special chars with this line:

```
$name = htmlspecialchars(trim(@$_POST["name"],' '),ENT_QUOTES);
```

Now they look like `'&quot;'`
To replace all quotes you have to decode them beforehand:

```
$url = preg_replace("![^a-zA-Z0-9]+!i", "-", strtolower(html_entity_decode($name,ENT_QUOTES)));
```

Comment: It works! but on first line is used htmlspecialchars then html_entity_encode.Is this a problem? can I use htmlspecialchars_decode.
Actually first varilable $name inserts into column name, second $url inserts into column url, So with $url I've make url slug for seo friendly url.

Comment: @amarullzamarullzz, yes, you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode($name, ENT_QUOTES);` as well

Comment: Without encode string can with regex to replace single and double quotes ?

Comment: without encoding it would look like `str_replace(array('\'', '"'), '', $str)`